# MIssing method in System.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller.

```
    public sealed class AccountsController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseAdapter _databaseAdapter;
        public AccountsController(IDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter)
        {
            _databaseAdapter = databaseAdapter;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("create")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser(CreateUserBindingModel createUserModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            if (! await _databaseAdapter.DoesAgentExist(createUserModel.UserName))
                return BadRequest();
            if (await _databaseAdapter.DoesAgentHaveAccount(createUserModel.UserName))
                return BadRequest();

            // Create account.
            var password = PasswordHelper.GeneratePassword(32);
            createUserModel.Password = password;
            createUserModel.ConfirmPassword = password;
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = createUserModel.UserName,
            };
            var addUserResult = await AppUserManager.CreateAsync(user, createUserModel.Password);
            if (!addUserResult.Succeeded)
                return GetErrorResult(addUserResult);
            var locationHeader = new Uri(Url.Link("GetUserById", new { id = user.Id }));
            return Created(locationHeader, ModelFactory.Create(user));
        }
    }
```

When I send the following fiddler to the create method.

> http://localhost:59430/api/accounts/create User-Agent: Fiddler
>
> Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json Host:
>   localhost:59430 Content-Length: 106
>
> { "UserName":"a.xxxxx", "Password":"xxxxxx",
>   "ConfirmPassword":"xxxxxx", }

It gets down to the following line:

`var addUserResult = await AppUserManager.CreateAsync(user, createUserModel.Password);`

Then the following exception occurs

> {     "message": "An error has occurred.",    "exceptionMessage": "Method
>   not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()'.",   "exceptionType":
>   "System.MissingMethodException",  "stackTrace": "   at
>   WebAuth.Controllers.BaseApiController.get_AppUserManager()\r\n   at
>   WebAuth.Controllers.AccountsController.d__3.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Users\stuarts\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\WebAuth\WebAuth\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line
>   76\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

Anyone know what is going on? I have no idea why it can't find that method.

My bin folders contains

System.Web.Http.dll
System.Web.Http.Owin.dll
System.Net.Http.dll

ApplicationUserManager

```
public sealed class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
                                                    IOwinContext context)
        {
            var appDbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var appUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(appDbContext));

            appUserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(appUserManager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
                RequireUniqueEmail = false,
            };
            appUserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 12,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireDigit = true
            };
            appUserManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 3;
            appUserManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            return appUserManager;
        }
    }
```

BaseApiController

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
        private ModelFactory _modelFactory;
        private readonly ApplicationUserManager _applicationUserManager = null;
        protected ApplicationUserManager AppUserManager => _applicationUserManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        protected ModelFactory ModelFactory => _modelFactory ?? (_modelFactory = new ModelFactory(Request, AppUserManager));
        protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
        {
            if (result == null)
                return InternalServerError();

            if (result.Succeeded) return null;

            if (result.Errors != null)
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        private readonly ApplicationRoleManager _appRoleManager = null;
        protected ApplicationRoleManager AppRoleManager => _appRoleManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
    }
```

Comment: don't you need to add the attribute [HttpGet] or something?
and in REST, something that creates should be a POST anyway if I'm not wrong

Comment: Why is your controller `sealed` and what is `BaseApiController`?

Comment: Can You share the code of `AppUserManager` property?

Comment: Is your create a GET or a POST? It looks like a GET when it probably should be a POST.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya, I've added AppUserManager class implementation.

Comment: Can you also share the property implementation of `AppUserManager` in BaseApiController

Comment: `Request.GetOwinContext()` this is the root cause of the issue. You need to check where this code is making get request and why that url doesn't have get support

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

When I was building there was build warnings going to the output window but not showing in the main error / warning window.

They were to do with assembly conflicts and said recommend putting the assembly redirect in the web.Config.

Once I had went through them all (around 80) it now works.

e.g.

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Yea, I got this too. Fwiw, in my case the issues started when I added web api capabilities to a regular asp.net mvc project. Confirm your solution worked.

Comment: it's weird, I already had an automatically inserted redirect, but, it was geared toward `4.1.0.0` and this answer prodded me to try upgrading the redirect.. which did the trick!

Comment: Thank you so much for this - fixed my issue!